# Как сделать проверку на выбранный radio?

Tags: javascript, html

Друзья,как проверить, какой был выбран radio. И в зависимости от выбранного radio показать нужны инпут?

Т.е. Если выбрал локацию, то показать в блоке `log` следующее:  `<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Локация">` или же `<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Хэштег">`

```
  <div>
    <input type="radio"  value="location" class="minimal">
    <label>Локация</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" value="tag" class="minimal">
    <label>Хэштег</label>
  </div>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```js
let log = document.getElementById('log');
let radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');

Array.from(radios).forEach(function(el){
 el.addEventListener('change', function(){
  log.innerHTML = `<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="${el.value}">`
 }) 
})
```

```html
  <div>
    <input type="radio"  name='input' value="location" class="minimal">
    <label>Локация</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name='input' value="tag" class="minimal">
    <label>Хэштег</label>
  </div>
<div id="log">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь моим примером. Не забывайте, что radio в рамках одной группы должны иметь одинаковый аттрибут name, иначе это будет считаться разными группами radio.

```js
let $radioGroup = $('.minimal');

$radioGroup.on('change', event => {
  let value = $radioGroup.filter(':checked').val();
  console.log('value',  value);
  //Далее любая ваша логика
  if(value === 'tag') {
  //...
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="groupName"  value="location" class="minimal">
    <label>Локация</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="groupName" value="tag" class="minimal">
    <label>Хэштег</label>
  </div>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Оба `checkbox` и `radio` при включенном состоянии имеют `:checked`, так что вот так:

```js
var buttons = $(".minimal");
var pattern, currentID, helperText;

$(buttons).click(function(){
  if($(this).filter(":checked").val() === "location"){
  //Вставляем нужный input
  currentID = "location";
  helperText = 'правильную локацию';
    $("#log").html("<input type='text' placeholder ='Введите локацию' name='loc' id="+ currentID +"/>");          
  pattern = /^((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)?([a-z0-9]{1})((\.[a-z0-9-])|([a-z0-9-]))*\.([a-z]{2,6})(\/?)$/;
  //Регулярка для проверки URL если что
  }
  else {
  //Вставляем нужный input
  currentID = "tagInput";
  helperText = 'правильный тег';
  $("#log").html("<input type='text' placeholder ='Введите тэг' name='tagging' id="+ currentID +"/>");    
   pattern = /^#(?=.*[^0-9])[a-zа-яё0-9]{1,29}$/i;
  //Регулярка для проверки тэга если что
  }
});

//И тут уже код для для проверки
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div>
    <input type="radio"  name='input' value="location" class="minimal">
    <label>Локация</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name='input' value="tag" class="minimal">
    <label>Хэштег</label>
  </div>
<div id="log"></div>
<output id="errorOutput"></output>
```